# php - xml indentation when using insertbefore

Tags: php, xml, dom, xpath, xml-parsing

This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <node/>
  <node>
    <child id="child1">
      <subchild1/>
      <subchild2/>
    </child>
    <child id="child2">
      <subchild1/>
      <subchild2/>
    </child>
    <child id="child3">
      <subchild1/>
      <subchild2/>
    </child>
  </node>
</root>
```

When I use insertbefore to insert a node, it works but the code isn't indented for that node:

```
$next = $xpath->query('/root/node/child[@id="child1"]/subchild2');
       // Create the new element
      $element = $dom->createElement('subchildmiddle'); 
      $parent = $xpath->query('/root/node/child[@id="child1"]');
       $parent->item(0)->insertBefore($element, $next->item(0));
```

the result is this:

```
<child id="child1">
      <subchild1/>
      <subchildmiddle><subchild2/>
    </child>
```

but I would that:

```
<child id="child1">
          <subchild1/>
          <subchildmiddle>
          <subchild2/>
        </child>
```

Is this possible? I used

```
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
```

(I've found it in previous questions) to format the code and it works, but not for subchildmiddle!

Comment: Indentation os not a requirement of XML, thats just for human readability

Comment: @RiggsFolly I know but I would do that for an examination

Comment: Tell your examiner that indentation whitespace is not significant in XML and that they should not be concerned about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preserveWhiteSpace` has to be disabled before you load the XML document. The option configures the parser so that it ignores whitespace text nodes.

Formatting will not always work perfectly, it adds whitespace nodes between the nodes. But the whitespace nodes can have meaning (for example `<strong class="firstLetter">H</strong>ello`). The serializer will try to avoid adding whitespace nodes that change the contents, throwing the formatting off.

Additionally your source can be optimized:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$document->formatOutput = TRUE;
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/root/node/child[@id="child1"][1]') as $parent) {
  $parent->insertBefore(
    $document->createElement('subchildmiddle'),
    $xpath->evaluate('subchild2', $parent)->item(0)
  );
}

echo $document->saveXml();
```

[Output](https://eval.in/513045):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <node/>
  <node>
    <child id="child1">
      <subchild1/>
      <subchildmiddle/>
      <subchild2/>
    </child>
    <child id="child2">
      <subchild1/>
      <subchild2/>
    </child>
    <child id="child3">
      <subchild1/>
      <subchild2/>
    </child>
  </node>
</root>
```

This way the first expression fetches the parent node. The second expression uses the parent node as context, if it returns an empty node list the node will be added as the last child. This avoids calling methods on `->item(0)` which will trigger errors if the expressions return empty lists.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! :D